# inferred type arguments [Any,Int] do not conform to method's type parameter bounds [T <: Comparable[T],V <: T]

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, comparable

```
val PROP_FEMALE:IProperty[java.lang.Integer] = PropertyInteger.create("female", 0,1)

worldIn.setBlockState(pos, state.withProperty(PROP_FEMALE, if (isFemale) 1 else 0), 2)
```

I'm coding a Minecraft Forge mod in Scala. I am trying to create the PropertyInteger for my blockstate. This works perfectly fine in normal Java. However, Scala is proving to be quite difficult to get it to work with is what I believe called implicit types?

For some reason this generates this error.

```
Error:(53, 45) inferred type arguments [Any,Int] do not conform to method withProperty's type parameter bounds [T <: Comparable[T],V <: T]
  worldIn.setBlockState(pos, withAge(0).withProperty(PROP_FEMALE, if (createFemale || isFemale) 1 else 0))
Error:(53, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : net.minecraft.block.properties.IProperty[Integer]
 required: net.minecraft.block.properties.IProperty[T]
      worldIn.setBlockState(pos, withAge(0).withProperty(PROP_FEMALE, if (createFemale || isFemale) 1 else 0))
```

Here is the `withProperty` method.

```
<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> IBlockState withProperty(IProperty<T> property, V value);
```

Here is the `PropertyInteger.create` method

```
public static PropertyInteger create(String name, int min, int max)
{
    return new PropertyInteger(name, min, max);
}
```

Here is all of the `PropertyInteger` class

```
public class PropertyInteger extends PropertyHelper<Integer>
{
    private final ImmutableSet<Integer> allowedValues;

    protected PropertyInteger(String name, int min, int max)
    {
        super(name, Integer.class);

        if (min < 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Min value of " + name + " must be 0 or greater");
        }
        else if (max <= min)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max value of " + name + " must be greater than min (" + min + ")");
        }
        else
        {
            Set<Integer> set = Sets.<Integer>newHashSet();

            for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i)
            {
                set.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            }

            this.allowedValues = ImmutableSet.copyOf(set);
        }
    }

    public Collection<Integer> getAllowedValues()
    {
        return this.allowedValues;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object p_equals_1_)
    {
        if (this == p_equals_1_)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (p_equals_1_ instanceof PropertyInteger && super.equals(p_equals_1_))
        {
            PropertyInteger propertyinteger = (PropertyInteger)p_equals_1_;
            return this.allowedValues.equals(propertyinteger.allowedValues);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        return 31 * super.hashCode() + this.allowedValues.hashCode();
    }

    public static PropertyInteger create(String name, int min, int max)
    {
        return new PropertyInteger(name, min, max);
    }

    public Optional<Integer> parseValue(String value)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return this.allowedValues.contains(integer) ? Optional.of(integer) : Optional.absent();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException var3)
        {
            return Optional.<Integer>absent();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the name for the given value.
     */
    public String getName(Integer value)
    {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a huge wall of code...

I think your example can be reduced to the following two lines:

```
def withProperty[T <: Comparable[T], V <: T](k: T, v: V) = ()
withProperty(42: java.lang.Integer, 42)
```

it results in a very similar error:

> error: inferred type arguments [Any,Int] do not conform to method
>   withProperty's type parameter bounds [T <: Comparable[T],V <: T]
>          withProperty(42: java.lang.Integer, 42)
>          ^ :13:
>
> error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : Integer
>    required: T

so I assume that the obvious workaround should also work in your code.

Simply ascribing the type of the second argument explicitly eliminates the error:

```
withProperty(42: java.lang.Integer, (if (true) 1 else 0): java.lang.Integer)
```

If you transfer it back into your code, it should look somewhat like this:

```
worldIn.setBlockState(
  pos, 
  state.withProperty(PROP_FEMALE, (if (isFemale) 1 else 0): java.lang.Integer), 
  2
)
```

Comment: The `PropertyInteger` class is from Minecraft's internal code, while large,  it was included in the question to aid understanding of the problem. So I wouldn't really warrant the inclusion superfluous.